# Enable instant run shortcut for build flavor

Tags: android, android-instant-run, instant-run

I have a specific build flavor that works with Instant Run. I want to be able to toggle Instant Run with a shortcut. Is this possible?

Comment: I hope you don't mean instant app as then my answer will look rubbish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enable instant run shortcut for build flavor`

> Short answer **NO you can't do that**

Instant run is an android studio feature and it cannot be driven from the app/build flavors of an app, you can enable it in your system and there is no way to trigger it in other person's system from the app,